# How to read a text file with php or bash and sort it?

Tags: php, bash, shell, text, sh

We have logging our disk array with iostat, and now have a 2 mb text file.
Is it possible to read the file contents, and sort all occurrences in some way, with php or bash?

We also have shell access, so if you're a commande guru, that's also a possibility.

We want to read and sort the following information in a text file, ascending, by some of the following `r/s`, `w/s`, `kr/s`, `kw/s`, `qlen`, `svc_t` or `%b` values.

Possible, or too difficult?

```
                        extended device statistics
device     r/s   w/s    kr/s    kw/s qlen svc_t  %b
da0       11.5  14.0   701.8   530.1    0   7.3  11
                        extended device statistics
device     r/s   w/s    kr/s    kw/s qlen svc_t  %b
da0        0.0   0.0     0.0     0.0    1   0.0   0
                        extended device statistics
device     r/s   w/s    kr/s    kw/s qlen svc_t  %b
da0        0.0  10.5     0.0   350.8    0 139.2 145
```

Comment: If text file grows, sort will be too expensive and slow. I think you should use SQLITE or MySql.If you want to use txt log files, I don't know about bash, but python can help a lot. you need maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to sort column 3 ("w/s"):

```
(echo 'device r/s w/s kr/s kw/s qlen svc_t %b'; grep '[0-9]' file | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | sort -n -k 3,3 ) | column -t
```

or this to sort column 7 ("svc_t"):

```
(echo 'device r/s w/s kr/s kw/s qlen svc_t %b'; grep '[0-9]' file | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | sort -n -k 7,7 ) | column -t
```

Output with `-k 7,7`:

```
device  r/s   w/s   kr/s   kw/s   qlen  svc_t  %b
da0     0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0    1     0.0    0
da0     11.5  14.0  701.8  530.1  0     7.3    11
da0     0.0   10.5  0.0    350.8  0     139.2  145
```

With `awk` or `printf` it's possible to align the colums right.

Comment: Absolutely amazing, how is this even possible. A huge tanks @Cyrus!